# Analyze Linux real-time characteristics

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Is there any way to analyze the RT characteristics of a linux kernel?

Just for fun I plan to study the behavior of a RT system on Raspberry Pi. I want to add events at each task swap, around each ISR etc. Those events shall contain the exact jiffy time, the processor, and the pid. The event information shall be stored on file. After the run I want to study the timing characteristics.

Of cause I want those measurements to disturb the system as little as possible.

Is there some kind of framework for doing this? Is it even possible to put events around ISRs (in a generic way)? I see this as a stackoverflow question as I'm willing to modify the code if necessary.

NB, I'm not looking for some kind of statistics view of aggregated data. I want it all! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at SystemTap and dtrace. They do what you want and more.

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/

http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/